# Creating a cancel for Valums uploader

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I'm looking to add a cancel button to my uploader but to take it out of the filuploader.js template as I need my cancel to pop out in a new div with a progress bar and show details on the file, progress etc

Any help here would be great as its the last part of a project and I've customized the uploader a great deal at this stage

I need to know how to set up the cancel button and allow it to cancel the file currently uploading

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You do not state which library you are using, but since you tagged both jQuery and FileUploader I suppose you are using jquery file uploader by Blueimp.

If that's the case, you could have a look at the demo page over [here](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) which has implemented an cancel button.

Answer (score 0):

Just return `FALSE` from onSubmit method:

```
var uploader = new qq.FileUploaderBasic({
    onSubmit: function(id, fileName){
        // return false to cancel upload
        return false;
    }
}
```